# php loop and array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a PHP class at the moment, that allows people to create new content blocks within a CMS, what I am wanting to be able to do is for the user to be able send to the class the inputs name, value, and and further options (think selected, and options for checkbox and radio buttons)

My first problem is that I am having trouble sending that data through to my class currently I am doing this,

```
homepageSlider->add_meta_box(
    'Book Info',
    array(
        'Year' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            array(
                'options' => 'Year 1',
                'Year 2',
                'Year 3'
            )
        ),
        'Genre' => 'text'
    )
);
```

Above you you can see that I am creating a content block called book info, and that content type has 2 form fields, Year (which has 3 checkboxes), and Genre which will be a text field.

My question is that this method does not seem to be working. I have no idea how I would loop through each portion of the above array to spit out all the information I would need? Can anyone shed any light on this?

Am I forming the array correctly for it to be multi-dimensional? This is what I believe it needs to be, or is it maybe a problem with my class?

```
function() use( $box_id, $box_title, $post_type_name, $box_context, $box_priority, $fields )
{
    add_meta_box(
        $box_id,
        $box_title,
        function( $post, $data )
        {
            global $post;

            // Nonce field for some validation
            wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'custom_post_type' );

            // Get all inputs from $data
            $custom_fields = $data['args'][0];

            // Get the saved values
            $meta = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

            //die(print_r($custom_fields));
            // Check the array and loop through it
            if( ! empty( $custom_fields ) )
            {

                /* Loop through $custom_fields */
                foreach( $custom_fields as $label => $type )
                {
                    $field_id_name  = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $data['id'] ) ) . '_' . strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $label ) );
                    echo '<label for="' . $field_id_name . '">' . $label . '</label>';
                    //self::getFormField($type, $field_id_name);
                    //<input type="'. self:getFormField($type) . '" name="custom_meta[' . $field_id_name . ']" id="' . $field_id_name . '" value="' . $meta[$field_id_name][0] . '" />';
                }
            }

        },
        $post_type_name,
        $box_context,
        $box_priority,
        array( $fields )
    );
}
```

Comment: did you mean "options" to be an array? And where is the class you are talking about? I only see some closures and functions.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4951805 here is my class

Comment: well, not meaning to discourage you, but it's a big procedural mess. It does too much. A class should have one single responsibility. And your class is just screaming to be refactored in multiple smaller classes.

Comment: How do you mean? The class deals with creation of and only the creation of post types?

Comment: If it was a Factory (deals with creation) then why does it have no create() Method? I see getFoo, registerThis, registerThat, addBar and save. All public. That doesnt really sounds like a Factory to me. Also, the methods in there are way too long. They do multiple things. Try to make one function doing one thing only.

Comment: Time to refactor I guess... :(

Comment: tip: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forming the array wrong.

```
homepageSlider->add_meta_box(   
    'Book Info',
    array(  
        'Year' => array('type' => 'checkbox' , 'options' => array('Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3')),  
        'Genre' => array('type' => 'text'),
    )  
);
```

But it stell looks messy. I believe that doing it with arrays like this is not an intuitive way. Have you thought about abstracting this into classes? I think something like this would be alot more cleaner:

```
class metaBox {
     private $inputFields = array();
     public function addField($inputFieldObject) {
       $this->inputFields[] = $inputFieldObject;
     }
}

class inputField {
     public $type = "";  // which tags
     public $attributes; // which attributes
}
```

Comment: How would I use those classes though?

Comment: why is &$inputFieldObject passed by reference?

Comment: No not all, I am fairly new to the OOP way of working. The I dont get is how would I fit these classes and method in with my original class?

Comment: so you can keep working with it after adding, having the changes reflected in the store.

Comment: you dont need references for that. objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: @sico87 you use a foreach() and implement some iterator for metaBox http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: @Gordon point taken. even tho technically.. it is not a reference but an identifier. so i am handing a reference to an identifier :D http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: yes I know, but that's completely irrelevant. References are in almost all cases bad practise in PHP.